# How do I replace blocks around me as I move?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Basically I need a command that as I move it replaces all of one type of block. when I search up commands like this it always fails because I am in 1.16.4 and the commands are outdated. basically like this command:

```
execute @p ~ ~ ~ fill ~-2 ~-1 ~2 ~2 ~ ~-2 minecraft:glass 0 replace minecraft:wool 3
```

except fixed for 1.16.4 because I know jack about minecraft commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put in a **Repeating Command Block** set to **Always Active** or in a **Ticking function**, the following command.

```
execute at <selector eg @p> run fill ~-5 ~-5 ~-5 ~5 ~5 ~5 <what block you want to replace with> replace <what block you want to replace>
```

This will replace any blocks that are `x` with a block that is `y` in a 10x10x10 box using `z` entities' location as the center. Make sure to change the entity selector to whatever you want, and the blocks to whatever you want.  The selector `@p` selects the nearest player.

## How it works

The `execute at` part runs the `fill` command at the entity's position who was selected with a selector.  The `~`'s in the `fill` command is used for using the run location as coordinates and you need one for each coordinate.  The number after the `~`'s is used for taking the run location and adding that number to it.  There is a point where the volume of the fill box is too high that the command won't execute.  That number is 32,768, which it isn't that high in terms of filling areas.